# How to change object to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am getting data something like this

```
{16: {email: 'tom@tom.tom', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}, 50: {email: 'boy@boy.boy', name: 'Boy', seq: 50}}
```

I want to change it to

```
{16: {email: '', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}, 50: {email: '', name: 'Boy', seq: 50}}
```

for just reset.
It is not an array, so I am kinda lost.
key values in the object are dynamic, so cannot just do like

```
const obj = {16: {email: 'tom@tom.tom', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}, 50: {email: 'boy@boy.boy', name: 'Boy', seq: 50}}
obj['16'] = {email: '', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}
```

and also it might have more than two objects, so also cannot just hard coding like

```
const obj = {16: {email: 'tom@tom.tom', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}, 50: {email: 'boy@boy.boy', name: 'Boy', seq: 50}}
obj['16'] = {email: '', name: 'Tom', seq: 16}
obj['50'] = {email: '', name: 'Tom', seq: 50}
```

could anyone help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert and manipulate your data as an array, I suggest that you use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Then you can reset the email values through forEach.

```js
let obj = {
  16: { email: 'tom@tom.tom', name: 'Tom', seq: 16 },
  50: { email: 'boy@boy.boy', name: 'Boy', seq: 50 },
};

let newObj = Object.entries(obj).map(([el, obj]) => ({ ...obj }));

newObj.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.email = '';
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I understood wrong the title of the question "How to change object to array?"

Comment: Lol, oops. They did not show an array in the "I want this" ;)

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = {
  16: {email: 'tom@tom.tom', name: 'Tom', seq: 16},
  50: {email: 'boy@boy.boy', name: 'Boy', seq: 50}
};

for (let key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    data[key].email = '';
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: It's a code-only answer without any explanation

Comment: And not an array ;) Did not see the title of the question